# 2 dim Fourier of partial derivative

Tags: fourier-analysis

The 2 dimensional Fourier transform of a function $f$ is defined like
$$ \mathbb{F}_2 f(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x,y) \exp(-i(X x + Yy)) dx dy$$
I know that in the one dimensional case, we have $$\mathbb{F}_1 f'(X) = iX \mathbb{F}_1 f(X)$$ , is it possible to derive a term $V$  so that 
$$ \mathbb{F}_2 (\frac{ df(x,y)}{dx}) = V   \mathbb{F}_2 (f(x,y)) ?$$

Comment: remember than bidimentional Fourier is just Fourier_x applied on Fourier_y.

Comment: Ok, it is all clear now, thank you